# Show that a bounded linear transformation is continuous

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, weak-convergence

I am not sure what this question is asking.

[image]

A linear operator $T$ between normed spaces X and Y is bounded if and only if it is a continuous linear operator. But weak topology is not metrizable. I guess I should use Closed Graph Theorem, is this a correct direction?

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: The closed graph theorem also doesn't apply to the weak topologies (generally). Just take the definition of the weak topology and check that the preimage of a weak neighbourhood of $0$ under $T$ is a weak neighbourhood of $0$.

Comment: @DanielFischer,thanks for this.

Answer (score 3):

We need to show that if $V$ is open in the weak topology of $Y$ then $T^{-1}[V]$ is open in the weak topology of $X$.

It clearly suffices to show that if $\mathscr S$ is a sub-basis of neighborhoods of zero in the weak topology of $Y$ and $W\in\mathscr S$, then $T^{-1}[W]$ is weak open in $X$.

A sub-basis of neighborhoods of zero in in the weak topology of $Y$ is obtained as
$$
\mathscr S=\{W_{\varphi,\varepsilon}:\varphi\in Y^*\,\&\,\varepsilon>0 \},
$$
where 
$$
W_{\varphi,\varepsilon}=\{y\in Y: \lvert\varphi(x)\rvert<\varepsilon\}
=\varphi^{-1}[(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)].
$$
Thus
$$
T^{-1}[W_{\varphi,\varepsilon}]=T^{-1}\big[\varphi^{-1}[(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)]\big]
=(\varphi\circ T)^{-1}[(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)].
$$
But $(\varphi\circ T)^{-1}[(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)]$ is open in the weak topology of $X$
since $\varphi\circ T\in X^*$.

Thus, indeed $T$ is continuous with respect to the weak topologies.